# NPM and Eslint: This is confusing, is that normal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, eslint

I am new to JS and I am trying to learn about linting. So, I am following a tutorial where we set the `lint` stage in the `package.json` file.

It looks like this: `"lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ."`

So in the terminal, when I run `./node_modules/.bin/eslint .` it is reporting back all the errors and warnings which is nice, as expected.

```
/Users/me/dev/webapps/templates/sample_node_project/index.js
  1:1   error    Expected 1 empty line after require statement not followed by another require  import/newline-after-import
  1:35  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi
  5:27  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi
  9:3   warning  Unexpected console statement                                                   no-console
  9:53  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi

✖ 5 problems (4 errors, 1 warning)
  4 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

But when I run `npm run lint`, I am getting this:

```
/Users/me/dev/webapps/templates/sample_node_project/index.js
  1:1   error    Expected 1 empty line after require statement not followed by another require  import/newline-after-import
  1:35  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi
  5:27  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi
  9:3   warning  Unexpected console statement                                                   no-console
  9:53  error    Missing semicolon                                                              semi

✖ 5 problems (4 errors, 1 warning)
  4 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sample_node_project@1.0.0 lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample_node_project@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2018-10-25T23_15_56_180Z-debug.log
```

So this throws an extra block of errors, which made me think that my `node` and `npm` is corrupt. Also, in the tutorial, the instructor is running `yarn lint` and he seems to be getting a lot less of that additional error block.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm run lint -s` will suppress the NPM error that you are seeing. ESLint gives you a non-zero exit code because of the lint errors.  NPM is basically saying that it can't run correctly because of the linting errors.  So yes, it's normal.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I also have noticed that a simple `"test": "echo \"Info: no test specified\" && exit 0"` will NOT generate the extra error block because of the `0` exit code. But this one `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",` throws the extra `ERR!`. But with the `-s` flag, the errors are suppressed.